# Qt Send Signal To Generate QDialog From Dynamic component

Tags: c++, qt, signals, signals-slots

In an attempt to create a small search GUI i wanted that whenever a user types in a TextEdit a program searches for all plausible results and shows them in a QGroupBox  inside a QScollArea.

I now want to add that when i click on the QGroupBox a new QDialog opens and shows the found result details. (That deletes itself when it closes - the small details window not the QGroupBox)

I managed to do everything except that when i click on the QGroupBox a new QDialog opens.

Here is my code:
organizer.h

```
class Organizer : public QMainWindow
{
  Q_OBJECT

private:
    QGroupBox* generateSearchResultEnclosure(const std::string& item_name,const std::string& classer_name, const unsigned row, const unsigned column);
    std::vector<QGroupBox*> search_results;
    QGridLayout *scroll_layout;
    unsigned nRows;
public:
    explicit Organizer(ItemOrganizer* item_org,QWidget *parent = 0);
   ~Organizer();

private slots:
    void generateClickedWindowItemResult(const std::string& exact_item_name, QWidget* parent);
    void on_searchField_textChanged();
    void on_pushButton_clicked();
    void on_pushButton_2_clicked();
    void updateFormComponentAddAvailable();
    void updateFormAdd2ClsrAvailable();
    void updateFormInsrtClsrAvailable();
    void on_addClasser_PushButton_clicked();

private:
    Ui::Organizer *ui;
    ComponentAdd *form_cmp_add;
    AddToClasser *form_add2_clsr;
    InsertClasser *form_insrt_clsr;
    ItemOrganizer *item_organizer;

};
```

organizer.cpp
(On QTextEdit text change):

```
void Organizer::on_searchField_textChanged()
{
   QWidget *wdg=ui->scrollArea->takeWidget();
   delete wdg;
   QWidget* blank_wdg=new QWidget();
   scroll_layout=new QGridLayout(blank_wdg);
   //widget->setLayout(layout);
   ui->scrollArea->setWidget(blank_wdg);
   ui->scrollArea->setWidgetResizable(true);

   if ((ui->searchField->toPlainText()).isEmpty())
      return;

   // Searching and generating a QGroupBox for each hit
   std::vector<SearchResult> res=item_organizer->search((ui->searchField->toPlainText()).toUtf8().constData());

   for (SearchResult &sr:res)
   {
       QGroupBox *win=generateSearchResultEnclosure(sr.cmp->name,sr.classer_name,sr.row,sr.column);
       scroll_layout->addWidget(win);
       win->show();
   }

   // Corecting QScrollArea widget size to fit all QGroupBox results
   unsigned row_count=0;
   if (scroll_layout->count()!=0)
       row_count=scroll_layout->rowCount();

   if(row_count>= nRows)
   {
         int h = 1.0*(ui->scrollArea->width() - scroll_layout->verticalSpacing()*(nRows+1.6))/nRows;
         int hCorrected = h*row_count + scroll_layout->verticalSpacing()*(row_count+2);
         ui->scrollArea->widget()->setFixedHeight(hCorrected);
   }
   ui->scrollArea->widget()->setFixedWidth(ui->scrollArea->viewport()->width());
}
```

organizer.cpp (Function that generates QGroupBox):

```
QGroupBox* Organizer::generateSearchResultEnclosure(const std::string& item_name,const std::string& classer_name, const unsigned row, const unsigned column)
{
QGroupBox* holder=new QGroupBox();
QVBoxLayout *layout_main=new QVBoxLayout;

QGroupBox *item_grp=new QGroupBox();
QGroupBox *clsr_grp=new QGroupBox();
QGroupBox *row_grp=new QGroupBox();
QGroupBox *column_grp=new QGroupBox();

QHBoxLayout *layout_item=new QHBoxLayout;
QHBoxLayout *layout_classer=new QHBoxLayout;
QHBoxLayout *layout_row=new QHBoxLayout;
QHBoxLayout *layout_column=new QHBoxLayout;

QLabel *item_label=new QLabel(tr("Item Name: "));
QLabel *clsr_label=new QLabel(tr("Classer Name: "));
QLabel *row_label=new QLabel(tr("Row: "));
QLabel *column_label=new QLabel(tr("Column: "));

QLineEdit *item_edit=new QLineEdit();
QLineEdit *classer_edit=new QLineEdit();
QLineEdit *row_edit=new QLineEdit();
QLineEdit *column_edit=new QLineEdit();

item_edit->setReadOnly(true);
classer_edit->setReadOnly(true);
row_edit->setReadOnly(true);
column_edit->setReadOnly(true);

item_edit->setText(item_name.c_str());
classer_edit->setText(classer_name.c_str());
row_edit->setText(QString::number(row));
column_edit->setText(QString::number(column));

layout_item->addWidget(item_label);
layout_item->addWidget(item_edit);

layout_classer->addWidget(clsr_label);
layout_classer->addWidget(classer_edit);

layout_row->addWidget(row_label);
layout_row->addWidget(row_edit);

layout_column->addWidget(column_label);
layout_column->addWidget(column_edit);

item_grp->setLayout(layout_item);
clsr_grp->setLayout(layout_classer);
row_grp->setLayout(layout_row);
column_grp->setLayout(layout_column);
layout_main->addWidget(item_grp);
layout_main->addWidget(clsr_grp);
layout_main->addWidget(row_grp);
layout_main->addWidget(column_grp);
layout_main->addStretch();
holder->setLayout(layout_main);
//holder->setMaximumHeight(ui->scrollArea->height()/2 - 10);
holder->setStyleSheet("QGroupBox {border: 2px solid gray; border-radius: 1px;} "
                      "QGroupBox::title {background-color: transparent; subcontrol-position: top left; padding:2 13px;}");

connect(holder, SIGNAL(clicked(bool)),this,SLOT(generateClickedWindowItemResult(item_name,holder)));
return holder;
}
```

Now i figured that **i cannot connect that SLOT to that signal** (since SIGNAL and SLOT need to have the same arguments)  even though something like that would work for me.

Here is the part where i generate that QDialog in case that is needed as part of a problem solving.  (Though its only form filling)

```
void Organizer::generateClickedWindowItemResult(const std::string& exact_item_name, QWidget *parent)
{
Component* cmp=item_organizer->getComponentByFullName(exact_item_name,true);
QDialog* cmp_window=new QDialog(parent);

QVBoxLayout *layout_main=new QVBoxLayout;

QGroupBox *item_name_grp=new QGroupBox();
QGroupBox *descr_grp=new QGroupBox();
QGroupBox *url_grp=new QGroupBox();
QGroupBox *tags_grp=new QGroupBox();
QGroupBox *quantity_grp=new QGroupBox();
QGroupBox *future_quantity_grp=new QGroupBox();

QHBoxLayout *layout_item_name=new QHBoxLayout;
QHBoxLayout *layout_descr=new QHBoxLayout;
QHBoxLayout *layout_url=new QHBoxLayout;
QHBoxLayout *layout_tags=new QHBoxLayout;
QHBoxLayout *layout_quantity=new QHBoxLayout;
QHBoxLayout *layout_future_quantity=new QHBoxLayout;

QLabel *item_name_label=new QLabel(tr("Item Name: "));
QLabel *descr_label=new QLabel(tr("Item Description: "));
QLabel *url_label=new QLabel(tr("Datasheet URL: "));
QLabel *tags_label=new QLabel(tr("Item Tags: "));
QLabel *quantity_label=new QLabel(tr("Item Current Quantity: "));
QLabel *future_quantity_label=new QLabel(tr("Item current+ordered quantity: "));

QLineEdit *item_name_edit=new QLineEdit();
QTextEdit *descr_edit=new QTextEdit();
QTextEdit *url_edit=new QTextEdit();
QTextEdit *tags_edit=new QTextEdit();
QLineEdit *quantity_edit=new QLineEdit();
QLineEdit *future_quantity_edit=new QLineEdit();

item_name_edit->setReadOnly(true);
descr_edit->setReadOnly(true);
url_edit->setReadOnly(true);
tags_edit->setReadOnly(true);
quantity_edit->setReadOnly(true);
future_quantity_edit->setReadOnly(true);

item_name_edit->setText(cmp->name.c_str());
descr_edit->setText(cmp->description.c_str());
url_edit->setText(cmp->url.c_str());

// TODO WRITE TAGS
//tags_edit->setText(cmp->tags);
quantity_edit->setText(QString::number(cmp->quantity));
future_quantity_edit->setText(QString::number(cmp->future_quantity));

layout_item_name->addWidget(item_name_label);
layout_item_name->addWidget(item_name_edit);

layout_descr->addWidget(descr_label);
layout_descr->addWidget(descr_edit);

layout_url->addWidget(url_label);
layout_url->addWidget(url_edit);

layout_tags->addWidget(tags_label);
layout_tags->addWidget(tags_edit);

layout_quantity->addWidget(quantity_label);
layout_quantity->addWidget(quantity_edit);

layout_future_quantity->addWidget(future_quantity_label);
layout_future_quantity->addWidget(future_quantity_edit);

item_name_grp->setLayout(layout_item_name);
descr_grp->setLayout(layout_descr);
url_grp->setLayout(layout_url);
tags_grp->setLayout(layout_tags);
quantity_grp->setLayout(layout_quantity);
future_quantity_grp->setLayout(layout_future_quantity);


layout_main->addWidget(item_name_grp);
layout_main->addWidget(descr_grp);
layout_main->addWidget(url_grp);
layout_main->addWidget(tags_grp);
layout_main->addWidget(quantity_grp);
layout_main->addWidget(future_quantity_grp);

layout_main->addStretch();
cmp_window->setLayout(layout_main);
cmp_window->setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose);
cmp_window->show();
}
```

How can i connect a on clicked signal from my QGroupBox to generate a QDialog and pass a parameter to QDialog as well as put that QGroupBox to be its parent?

Comment: Qt5: `connect(holder, &QGroupBox::clicked,[this](){generateClickedWindowItemResult(item_name,holder)});`
`

Comment: In Qt4 create an appropriate slot for your signal, and in it call the function generateClickedWindowItemResult

Comment: I have Qt5 installed (If i go to Tools->Options->Qt Versions i have 
Qt 5.9.2 in PATH (qt5) /usr/lib/qt5/bin/qmake ) 

However building gives a bunch of errors 
stray '\342', stray \200, ...

Comment: In Qt 5 you can connect the signals to lambda functions, in that lambda function call the slot you want as I have shown in the example.

Comment: I checked and added a Qt5 kit and tried building it with just that however i still get a lot of those 'stray' errors.

Also it says that the lambda has no capture default and that item_name and holder are not captured

Comment: Add `CONFIG += c++11` to .pro

Comment: Pushed that at the end of Organizer.pro file and even did a clean All and clean Project however the errors still remain (im on linux so i even tried CONFIG += c++0x in case thats a g++ flag and that didn't work also)

Comment: I work on Linux, and from Qt 5.6 to Qt 5.10 it works correctly, check your syntax.

Comment: See this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/272741/how-to-fix-compilation-errors-that-mention-stray-342-and-stray-200, do not copy and paste the text, transcribe it.

Comment: Ok for some weird reason there was a weird character when copying from SO. I retyped it and now i only have the 

'In lambda function: item_name is not captured, holder is not captured'
I think that i should put item_name,holder instead of this in the lambda right ?

Comment: Use: `connect(holder, &QGroupBox::clicked,[this, &item_name, holder](){generateClickedWindowItemResult‌​(item_name,holder)})‌​;`

Comment: `connect(holder, &QGroupBox::clicked,[this,item_name,holder](){generateClickedWindowItemResult(item_name,holder);});`
Now it compiles but still doesn't work i will debug and check if it goes the way i wanted it. Thanks for the lambda hint !

Comment: Clicking and following the code in GDB basically tells me that clicking on the QGroupBox never enters the generateClickedWindowItemResult.

Comment: enter the callback?

Comment: Yes. QGroupBox::clicked should call generateClickedWindowItemResult , however it never enters the function (generateClickedWindowItemResult). 
Is it possible that QGroupBox::clicked doesn't emit a signal ?

Comment: I think that being item_name a local variable generates that behavior, also your implementation is not very clean, I recommend restructuring your application, it will be untenable later.

Comment: I tried connect(holder, &QGroupBox::clicked,[this](){QMessageBox::information(0,tr("Clicked"),"clicked!");});
And it doesn't display The message box, meaning it probably isn't that it item is a local variable. 

I'm new at Qt 4-5 Days experience tops so im trying to get the hang of it all

Comment: I can not do anything, as I say your code is not clean so maybe the error is elsewhere, that's what happens when the code is messy.

Comment: I think that you might misunderstand what the `clicked` signal of `QGroupBox` class does. Did you [read the docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgroupbox.html#clicked)?

Comment: Y i realized that after i debugged some more. I will prob post an answer to how i solved the issue. Needed to manually program the clicked signal since QGroupBox has its own interpretation of clicked (mainly the checkboxes and other checkable components)